# Flutter как реализовать секундомер так чтобы он работал в фоне, когда приложение переключилось на другой экран или закрыто?

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем доброго времени суток!
Суть вопроса в чем , есть экран с кнопками(допустим их 2) , при нажатии на которые запускается секундомер , но проблема в том что нужно сохранить работу секундомера в фоне, когда пользователь переключиться на другой экран приложения и(или) свернет его, а когда откроет экран с кнопками снова отобразить секундомер с актуальным значением с момента старта.

секундомер я пока реализовал так

```
StopWatchTimer _stopWatchTimer = StopWatchTimer(
      mode: StopWatchMode.countUp,
      onChangeRawSecond: (value) => print('presetMillisecond:  $value'),
      onChangeRawMinute: (value) => print('onChangeRawMinute $value'),
    );
```

и брал из него значение так

```
StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: _stopWatchTimer.secondTime,
      initialData: _stopWatchTimer.secondTime.value,
      builder: (context, snap) {
        var value = snap.data;
        return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: _stopWatchTimer.secondTime,
      initialData: _stopWatchTimer.secondTime.value,
      builder: (context, snap) {
        var value = snap.data;
        return Card(
              child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  selectedButton = key;
                        if (!_stopWatchTimer.isRunning) {
                          _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);
                          _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.start);
                        } else {
                          selectedButton = '';
                          _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);
                          _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.stop);
                        }
                  }
                },
                child: 
                       Text(   '${value.toString()}',
                                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(6, 8, 15, 1),
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                  )),
                                            )        
              ),
            ));
      },
    );,
```

Читал что есть вариант сделать так через AndroidAlarmManager , но вроде как он перестает работать через пол часа в фоне .
кто что думает ? как лучше сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Короче запилил глобальный сервис с таймером и отдельно просто прикрутил AndroidAlarmManager чтобы он следил за открытием закрытием приложения .

Пока что выглядит так
Сам сервис

```
class TimerService extends ChangeNotifier {
  Stopwatch _watch = Stopwatch();
  var _timer;

  Duration get currentDuration => _currentDuration;
  Duration _currentDuration = Duration.zero;
 bool get isRunning => _timer != null;

 TimerService() {
    _watch = Stopwatch();
 }

String get getTime => getDisplayTime(_currentDuration.inMilliseconds);

 static String getDisplayTime(){
 //перевод человеко читаемый вид(если кому надо пишите скину код) 
 }

void _onTick(Timer timer) {
  _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;
  print(_currentDuration);
  // notify all listening widgets
  notifyListeners();
}

void start() {
   if (_timer != null) return;
   _timer = null;
   _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _onTick);
   _watch.start();
   notifyListeners();
}

void stop() {
  _timer?.cancel();
  _watch.stop();
  _currentDuration = _watch.elapsed;
  notifyListeners();
}

void reset() {
  stop();
  _watch.reset();
  _currentDuration = Duration.zero;
  notifyListeners();
}
}

 class TimerServiceProvider extends InheritedWidget {
   const TimerServiceProvider({Key? key, required this.service, required Widget 
   child})
    : super(key: key, child: child);

  final TimerService service;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TimerServiceProvider old) => service != old.service;
}
```

и слушатель

```
                          AnimatedBuilder(
                            animation: globalsVars.timerServ,
                            builder: (context, child) {
                              return Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5 , left: 12),
                                  decoration: (selectedButton == key)
                                      ? BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.white10,
                                      width: 2,
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  )
                                      : null,
                                  child:  Text(
                                    '${globalsVars.timerServ.getTime}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                                        )),
                                  ))
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
```

Пока что более элегантного решения не придумал ... так что если у кого есть мысли буду рад вашему мнению